# Assigning javascript value to Model variable in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an HTML select box called ddlLocation.  When the value changes in the select box a change event javascript method gets fired.  In the change event code, I want to assign the changed value to my ASP.NET variable called Model.Location.

I am trying to do this:

```
$("#ddlLocation").change(function (evt) {
    <%Model.Location =%> $('#ddlLocation option:selected').text();<%; %>
});
```

It keeps crashing and saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'"

Please Help!!!

Comment: you cannot do this , why not pass the selected value as a query string and bind it to a view model .. this happens usually on form submits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this that way. you have to post the value to a controller method that will assign the location.

```
$("#ddl3PVLocationSourceCodes").change(function (evt) {
   var locationValue = $('#ddlLocation option:selected').text();
   $.post("/YourController/AssignLocation", { location: locationValue });  
});
```

Hope it helps.